# How to restrict the parent node update if it does not have a child using data weave 2.0?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

In my case, I have updating **DTOCoverageItem** node FullTermAmt attribute value from the incoming request.

I have to restrict the **DTOCoverageItem** node updation, if does not contains DTOSteps as a child node.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DTOApplication id="Application-1054516507-2054171867" ApplicationNumber="QT-00009188" >    
    <DTOLine id="Line-1977956099-1487151749" StatusCd="Active" LineCd="CommercialAuto" FullTermAmt="0.00" RatingService="ManualRate" >
        <DTORisk id="Risk-1669201459-335100744" TypeCd="CommercialVehicle" LocationRef="Location-95582176-1640749066" FullTermAmt="0.00" Status="Active" >
            <DTOCoverage id="Coverage-8867140-2034354070" Status="Active" CoverageCd="CARGO" FullTermAmt="0.00" Description="Cargo">
                <DTOCoverageItem id="CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517" Status="Active" CoverageItemCd="ScheduledItem" FullTermAmt="0.00" >
                    <DTOSteps id="Steps-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517">
                        <DTOStep id="Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-FinalRate" Name="Final Rate" Factor="0.00" Value="13.60" Status="Cleared">
                            <DTOSteps id="Steps-Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-FinalRate">
                                <DTOStep id="Step-Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-FinalRate-BaseRate" Name="Base Rate" Operation="=" Factor="10.78" Value="0.00" Status="Cleared"/>
                                <DTOStep id="Step-Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-FinalRate-Theft" Name="Theft" Operation="+" Factor="2.10" Value="0.00" Status="Cleared"/>
                                <DTOStep id="Step-Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-FinalRate-EarnedFreight" Name="Earned Freight" Operation="+" Factor="0.72" Value="0.00" Status="Cleared"/>
                                <DTOStep id="Step-Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-FinalRate-RefrigerationBreakdown" Name="Refrigeration Breakdown" Operation="+" Factor="0.00" Value="13.60" Status="Cleared"/>
                            </DTOSteps>
                        </DTOStep>
                        <DTOStep id="Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-LimitPer1000" Name="Limit Per 1000" Operation="*" Factor="100.00" Value="0.00" Status="Cleared"/>
                        <DTOStep id="Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-Deductible" Name="Deductible" Operation="*" Factor="0.85" Value="0.00" Status="Cleared"/>
                        <DTOStep id="Step-CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517-ModFactor" Name="Mod Factor" Operation="*" Factor="1.21" Value="1399.00" Status="Cleared"/>
                    </DTOSteps>
                    <DTOLimit id="Limit-1790462058-1228558954" LimitCd="ItemLimit1"/>
                    <DTOCoverageData id="CoverageData-1696958602-512988804" CoverageDataCd="ClassCd" Value="CIced"/>
                </DTOCoverageItem>
                <DTOLimit id="Limit-1200709238-1764617886" LimitCd="Limit1" Value="100000"/>
                <DTODeductible id="Deductible-99803092-61708522" DeductibleCd="Deductible1" Value="1000"/>
                <DTOSteps id="Steps-Coverage-8867140-2034354070">
                    <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-8867140-2034354070-ScheduledItem#1" Name="Scheduled Item #1" Desc="Iced or Refrigerated Produce" Operation="+" Factor="1399" Value="1399" Status="Cleared"/>
                    <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-8867140-2034354070-ScheduledItem#2" Name="Scheduled Item #2" Desc="General Freight" Operation="+" Factor="0" Value="0" Status="Cleared"/>
                </DTOSteps>
                <DTOCoverageItem id="CoverageItem-1693945123-524500811" Status="Active" CoverageItemCd="ScheduledItem" FullTermAmt="0.00" >
                    <DTOLimit id="Limit-1312834274-1499345391" LimitCd="ItemLimit1"/>
                    <DTOCoverageData id="CoverageData-18362738-128450429" CoverageDataCd="ClassCd" Value="Cgene"/>
                </DTOCoverageItem>
            </DTOCoverage>                          
          </DTORisk>
    </DTOLine>
</DTOApplication>
```

Data weave 2.0 Code which i have:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

fun CARGOtransformSteps(x, index)=
    x  match {
      case is Object -> x mapObject 
        if  ($$ as String == "DTOSteps")
        {
                    DTOSteps: DTOStep @(Order:"1", Name:"Final Rate", Value: "1" ) : DTOSteps :null
        }
        else 
            (($$): $) 
      else -> $
}
    
fun CARGOtransformCoverage(x, index)=
    x match {
      case is Object -> x mapObject 
        if ($$ as String == "DTOCoverageItem" and $$.@CoverageItemCd == "ScheduledItem" and $$.@Status == "Active")
            { 
                DTOCoverageItem @(( $$.@ - "FullTermAmt" ), FullTermAmt: "100" ):  CARGOtransformSteps($, index)
            }
        else 
            (($$): CARGOtransformCoverage($, index+1)) 
      else -> $
    }
    
fun DTORisktransform(x, index)=
    x match {
      case is Object -> x mapObject 
        if ($$ as String == "DTORisk" and $$.@id == "Risk-1669201459-335100744" )
            { 
                DTORisk @(( $$.@ )): 
                    CARGOtransformCoverage($, index)
            }
        else 
            (($$): DTORisktransform($, index+1)) 
      else -> $
    }   
---
DTORisktransform(payload,1)
```

The above dataweave code will updating the all DTOCoverageItem nodes, it's not restricting the update if it doesn't contains DTOSteps.

for the above code, the **FullTermAmt** values is updating as "100" in **DTOCoverageItem**. but it doesn't has **DTOSteps** as child.

Expected Response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DTOApplication id="Application-1054516507-2054171867" ApplicationNumber="QT-00009188">
  <DTOLine id="Line-1977956099-1487151749" StatusCd="Active" LineCd="CommercialAuto" FullTermAmt="0.00" RatingService="ManualRate">
    <DTORisk id="Risk-1669201459-335100744" TypeCd="CommercialVehicle" LocationRef="Location-95582176-1640749066" FullTermAmt="0.00" Status="Active">
      <DTOCoverage id="Coverage-8867140-2034354070" Status="Active" CoverageCd="CARGO" FullTermAmt="0.00" Description="Cargo">
        <DTOCoverageItem id="CoverageItem-988993575-1827862517" Status="Active" CoverageItemCd="ScheduledItem" FullTermAmt="100">
          <DTOSteps>
            <DTOStep Order="1" Name="Final Rate" Value="1">
              <DTOSteps/>
            </DTOStep>
          </DTOSteps>
          <DTOLimit id="Limit-1790462058-1228558954" LimitCd="ItemLimit1"/>
          <DTOCoverageData id="CoverageData-1696958602-512988804" CoverageDataCd="ClassCd" Value="CIced"/>
        </DTOCoverageItem>
        <DTOLimit id="Limit-1200709238-1764617886" LimitCd="Limit1" Value="100000"/>
        <DTODeductible id="Deductible-99803092-61708522" DeductibleCd="Deductible1" Value="1000"/>
        <DTOSteps id="Steps-Coverage-8867140-2034354070">
          <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-8867140-2034354070-ScheduledItem#1" Name="Scheduled Item #1" Desc="Iced or Refrigerated Produce" Operation="+" Factor="1399" Value="1399" Status="Cleared"/>
          <DTOStep id="Step-Coverage-8867140-2034354070-ScheduledItem#2" Name="Scheduled Item #2" Desc="General Freight" Operation="+" Factor="0" Value="0" Status="Cleared"/>
        </DTOSteps>
        <DTOCoverageItem id="CoverageItem-1693945123-524500811" Status="Active" CoverageItemCd="ScheduledItem" FullTermAmt="0.00">
          <DTOLimit id="Limit-1312834274-1499345391" LimitCd="ItemLimit1"/>
          <DTOCoverageData id="CoverageData-18362738-128450429" CoverageDataCd="ClassCd" Value="Cgene"/>
        </DTOCoverageItem>
      </DTOCoverage>
    </DTORisk>
  </DTOLine>
</DTOApplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to the condition to transforming the `DTOCoverageItem` keys that it must not have `DTOSteps` children. That can be encapsulated into a function for simplicity.

Because you didn't clarify which condition is that, I'll assume it is:

```js
        if ($$ as String == "DTOCoverageItem" and $$.@CoverageItemCd == "ScheduledItem" and $$.@Status == "Active")
```

So I would add something like `and isKeyInChild($, "DTOSteps")` at the end of the condition.

Then implement the function `isKeyInChild()` as:

```js
fun isKeyInChild(x, key) =
    x match {
        case is Array  -> x dw::core::Arrays::some (isKeyInChild($, key)) // check if some object or child of the array contains the key
        case is Object -> (namesOf(x) contains key) or (valuesOf(x) dw::core::Arrays::some (isKeyInChild($, key))) // check if the object contains the key or any child values contain the key
        else -> false // anything else can not contain the key
    }
```

Comment: I have done changes as per your suggestion. It's not working as expected. for the second "DTOCoverageItem" nodes attribute FullTermAmt  values also updated to 100. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: I'm reading the question and the condition desired as originally described was unclear. Please clarify in the question if elements with DTOSteps children must or must not be updated.

Comment: I realized that inverting the condition the result seems to match the expected output. I also changed the usage of keysOf() to namesOf() though the result seems the same because it is more appropriate.